# How to add specific item in SelectList at last position?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Following  expression return list of city. the name "xyz" city is in list.  I want this city name at last position of selectList.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(M => M.CityId, GetCity(), "-Select-", new { @class = "form-control" })

public static SelectList GetCity()
{
    try
    {
        using (var context = new DBContext())
        {
            var list = context.Table.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.REF_TYPE == "CITY").OrderBy(x => x.DESCRIPTION).ToList();
            return new SelectList(list, "REF_ID", "DESCRIPTION");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       throw ex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, list will show the items in the order in which they have been added. So you can remove and add the item again:

```
var list = context.Table.AsNoTracking().Where(x => x.REF_TYPE == "CITY").OrderBy(x => x.DESCRIPTION).ToList();
var xyz = list.First(entry => entry.Text == "xyz");
list.Remove(xyz);
list.Add(xyz);
```

A cleaner way might be to write a custom `IEqualityComparer` that you can use with the `OrderBy` clause.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
.OrderBy(x => x.DESCRIPTION)
```

with

```
.OrderBy(x => x.DESCRIPTION == "xyz" ? 1 : 0).ThenBy(x => x.DESCRIPTION)
```

This way you are effective telling the query that "xyz" is bigger than any of the other items. Since the other items will be considered equal by the `OrderBy` part, they will be effectively ordered by the `ThenBy` part.

Comment: Thanks @Stoev its working. but Can you explain the logic how it works?

Comment: You are welcome. I already did my best to try explaining it after the code snippet.